# Taking file as input in python

Tags: python

Iam trying to code a python program to accept a file from the user and then carry out operations on the file please any assistance will be highly appreciated

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Please (re)take the [tour], read about [ask] and please provide a [mre] of your attempts

Comment: You want the file path as input from the user ? or any pop type something, that will ask the user to browse and chose the file ?

Comment: Yes mr Pranbir Sarkar that's what I need to allow the user browse for the file

Comment: Just search this question up, it has many answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
selectfile = input("Enter Filename: ")
with open(selectfile, 'r') as f:
    file=f.read().splitlines()
print(file)
```

This will work if I am not mistaken. The first line is opening the file, then the rest are reading it.

Comment: Thanks am very grateful it did exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

We'll need better instructions to be able to help you, but one thing I've used previously when working with csv files is this:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_filename = input("Please enter your filename: ")
data = pd.read_csv(f"{csv_filename}.csv", low_memory=False)
```

Comment: Who's to say that OP need to work with csv files or even has `pandas` available? Please refrain from answering such questions, only answer well-asked questions. This is clearly described in [answer]